# curl in php, iframe and forms

Tags: php, forms, iframe, curl

I have a sales page on my site which I am trying to configure.

The payment process I am trying to nail is this:

sales page loads, with info form in iframe, customer fills in form, clicks submit - then only the iframe then reloads...and leads to a second iframe (which is the payment processors iframe)

Once payment is made successfully, the customer is sent (still within the iframe) to a successful payment page. The payment processor adds some extra strings into the url, which then need to be compiled into a message and sent as an email to me.

I can successfully create and call up the form iframe, and the payment processors - but struggling with how to connect the two, and create the third.

Any help would be appreciated - I am a php learner and chucked myself in at the deep end, so sorry in advance for that!

Would it be possible to do this all within one php page or is the way I am attempting the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iFrames are never pretty.  Why not use AJAX to achieve the same result as the iframes?

If you want to use the iFrames, what exactly are you having difficult with?  The transfer of the url variables?

EDIT:

You should be able to transfer your variables through the iframe with standard url format:

```
<iframe src="landing_page.php?var=str&var2=str2" name="frame_name"></iframe>
```

Then "landing_page.php" can access these variables by calling them with the "get" method :

```
<?php
      echo $_GET['var'];
      echo $_GET['var2'];
?>
```

Or, since you are changing the iframe by clicking on (what I assume) is a link you could achieve the same result by:

```
<a href="landing_page.php?var=str&var2=str2" target="frame_name">Click to load new iframe</a>
```

And "landing_page.php" would have access with the same method as before.

However, I still recommend using AJAX just because iframes are mostly outdated and unnecessary.  I have yet to encounter any issue with AJAX and browser compatibility.  If that's the route you want, I would recommend using the [jquery library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get you up and running quickly.  If you're interested in that, or still have trouble with the iframes, let me know.

EDIT 2:

So it seems like you should still be able to access these url vars using the php $_GET method on your confirmation page and then send your email using [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).  An example is below (substitute the actual variable names from the url for my made up ones):

```
//retrieve 'email' var from url
$to = $_GET['email'];

//enter title of email
$subject = 'Your Payment Confirmation';

//create your message and retrieve 'name' and 'amount' var from url
$msg = "Thank you, ".$_GET['name']."! Your payment of ".$_GET['amount']." 
        was approved!";

//if you want to have a custom "FROM" in the email header
$headers = 'From: somename@example.com';

//send mail to customer
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);

//send to yourself as well
mail('youremail@domain.com',$subject,$msg,$headers)
```

NOTE: if you are testing this on localhost, you will need to enable the mail function on your local server or else the mail won't send.

EDIT 3:

Use [explode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) to parse the Note var with a semicolon as the delimiter.  You will then have an array of your values.  For example:

```
//explode the note var from url
$vars = explode(';', $_GET['Note']);

//echo values of $vars array
for($i=0; $i<count($vars); $i++) {
      echo $vars[$i]. '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I am using iframes because I am more familiar with them then ajax. Does ajax work on all browsers? I am having difficulty with passing variables between the form, and the payment processing iframe, and also with the transfer of the url variables into a confirmation email. Thanks again

Comment: thanks a lot for that, really helpful and complete answer!

i am definitely going to try the AJAX method later, however I first want to try and nail the iframe method because i think i am nearly there. how can i do the opposite of what you said, and input some values on the end of a url from php, then use curl to dynamically get the new url given by the payment processing, and then refresh the iframe currently on the page with the new url given by the payment processing?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the user enters his/her payment info, clicks submit, and then you want to take this info and throw it onto the end of a url (i.e. payment_confirmation.php?var=str) and transfer the iframe to the payment confirmation page where you will send an email to yourself by accessing these url vars.  If that's the case, why not simply use a <form> on the payment_processing page with action="payment_confirmation.php" method="get"?  Then payment_confirmation.php can access the input vars using the same get method as above.

Comment: hi again, it is not quite that simple i am afraid. the user enters their name and email and an amount, the name and email need to be compiled into a note, and the amount into a tariff variable - these are then placed at the end of a url...this then sends to a payment processing page (which is from a payment processing provider). the user completes payment, and the payment processor then sends the user to a success or failure page, along with some other parameters in the note. i then need to skim out the parameters and compile them into an email to send both me and the client. hpe that helps?

Comment: Ah yes, it's never simple is it?  Well unfortunately I've never used a payment processing provider (or curl for the matter), but I'll still try to help.  After they process it (and approve it), what is the url that they are directing the user to (i.e. your payment_confirmation page)?  Do they include any of the vars there or is it in a diff form?

Comment: the output is in this form: http://mydomain.com/payment-problem/?SessionID=582506&Note=john&Status=203&Operator=

the note is in the form email;name;ipaddress

so essentially what i am trying to do, is to get the all the items out of the url and send an email of the form

send to - my email, customers email
Message - dear (name), thanks for your order, session id, etc..

Comment: thanks for the edit - the problem is that the url appendages look like this ?SessionID=582506&Note=john&Status=203&Operator=

and the email address, name, amount and ip address are all stored in the note, separated by a semicolon.

is there a way to parse the note value and extract the data (that is limited by semicolons) from it?

Comment: Could the same thing be done using POST instead of GET in php ?

Comment: If you're running an Ajax function I don't see why not. If you're using Iframes  I dont think it will work